# How to determine the light rays difference according to book by Okamoto?

Tags: visible-light, geometric-optics, waveguide

In the very beginning of the book "Fundamentals of Optical Waveguides" by Okamoto, there is a description of light ray propagation in the waveguide. I provided an updated Figure from it:
[image: light ray propagation in the waveguide]

According to Okamoto, the distance RQ between points Q and R is defined as $2a/tan(\phi) - 2a*tan(\phi)$, which is MQ - MR, according to the updated Figure. I can see how MQ is calculated to be $2a/tan(\phi)$ from the NMQ triangle, however I cannot understand how MR can be calculated to be $2a*tan(\phi)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $[MR]=2a\tan\phi$ because the ray $\vec{NQ}$ is at a critical angle, such that it suffers total reflection, in other words its $\mathbf {\text{incident angle = reflected angle}}$ and, therefore, the angle that the ray reflected from $R$ has with line $RQ$ is also $\phi$. Consequently, the angle, $ \measuredangle MNR$, at point $N$ of the triangle $\bigtriangleup MNR$ is also $\phi$.